# Cant get access to 'this' object by dynamicly string

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i have some method in my Nuxt + TS App. I try to do some function `

```
nextPage(paginationName: string): void {
      this[`${paginationName}Data`].pagination
        .nextPage()
        .then((newPage: number) => {
          this.getData(paginationName, newPage);
        });
    },
```

and get access to my computed by 'this' but my complier can't do this with error  `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`. With `@ts-ignore` it will be work fine, but i must revome this line. This is my computed

```
soonData(): ISoonData {
      const soonData = this.$store.getters['soonData'];
      const pagination = new Pagination(
        Number(soonData.currentPage),
        soonData.maxPage
      );
      return new soonData(soonData, pagination, 'soon');
    },
```

I use Options-api to declare my components  `export default Vue.extend({})`

Comment: This is because `Component` from Vue doesn't have an index signature. Add an interface to your component `extends Vue implements {[key: string]: any }`

Comment: Can you say where and how i must use this interface?

Comment: The compiler (correctly) complains about that access because the value of the key isn't known until *runtime*, so there's no way it can be verified at *compile time*. You'll have to cast it, something like `this[\`${paginationName}Data\` as keyof typeof this].pagination`

Comment: Show how you make your component

Comment: @Ohgodwhy add it to description

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by context substitution
like:

```
let _this: any 

export default Vue.extend({
...

methods: {
  nextPage(paginationName: string): void {
  _this[`${paginationName}Data`].pagination
    .nextPage()
    .then((newPage: number) => {
      this.getData(paginationName, newPage);
    });
},
}
...
created () {
  _this=this
}

})
```